# display only when boolean is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have something like this in the controller:

```
    def create        
        @found = false
   end
```

and something like this in the view:

```
<% if found? %>
    <h1> ok </h1> 
<% else %>
   <h1> not ok </h1> 
<% end %>
```

but it is not working I tried something like this as well `<% if @found= true%>` and it didn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you tried  found == true ?

Comment: @JoséLopezCoronado that solved it ! lol just a silly mistake. Thanks

Comment: use ternary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if @found %>
    <h1> ok </h1> 
<% else %>
   <h1> not ok </h1> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the best way can be by using ternary operator:

```
<%= @found? ? '<h1> ok </h1>' : '<h1> not ok </h1>' %>
```